# Xerces-C: Migration from v2.x to v3.x?

Tags: c++, xml, api, upgrade, xerces-c

I would like to migrate a project (legacy code which I am not quite familiar with) from Xerces-C v2.x to v3.x.

It turns out that Xerces-C v3 dropped the DOMBuilder class. The [migration archive](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/migrate-archive-3.html#DeprecatedAPI300) tells me this:

> ...a number of DOM interfaces (DOMBuilder, DOMWriter, DOMInputSource, etc.) were replaced as part of the the final DOM Level 3 specification conformance work.

That's nice. But is there any guide on how to migrate code that relies on these classes to the new API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replacements for removed APIs:

- Use `XercesDOMParser` or `DOMLSParser` instead of `DOMBuilder` ([more info](http://markmail.org/message/5ztcgzgb5a7ldys3)):

  > xercesDOMParser->setCreateCommentNodes(true);
- Use `DOMLSSerializer` instead of `DOMWriter`:

  > DOMLSSerializer* writer = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl)->createLSSerializer(); 
  >   DOMConfiguration* dc = writer->getDomConfig();
  >   dc->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMErrorHandler,errorHandler);
  >   dc->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTDiscardDefaultContent,true);
- Use `DOMLSInput` instead of `DOMInputSource`.

See also:

- ["Xerces-C++ API Reference 3.1.1"](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classes.html)
- ["Xerces-C++ API Reference 2.8.0"](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classes.html)

Comment: An illustrative example of how to convert `DOMWriter` to `DOMLSSerializer` can be found here: http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/ticket/1399