# Need replacement APIs for Xerces DOMWriter

Tags: xml

As per new Xerces API migration from Xerces-C v2.x to v3.x, I need to migrate my code which uses DOMWriter and DOMBuilder APIs.

I already went through **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678396/xerces-c-migration-from-v2-x-to-v3-x)** link and knew that DOMLSParser is used instead of DOMBuilder and DOMLSSerializer is used instead of DOMWriter.

But, I could only found limited APIs which exact match with older ones.
So, coming to point, I just want simillar APIs in DOMLSSerializer class for DOMWriter class:-

canSetFeature();

setFeature();

Also, I want similar API for following DOMBuilder class:-

setErrorHandler();

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xerces-C: Migration from v2.x to v3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678396/xerces-c-migration-from-v2-x-to-v3-x)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I am trying to figure this out right now myself and figured I would share what I found. canSetFeature and setFeature have been replaced by canSetParameter and setParameter. Though you don't call these functions on DOMLSSerializer but instead on DOMConfiguration.

This link shows you how they are translated:
https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html#DOMLSSerializer