# Migration from Xerces 2.X to Xerces 3.X

Tags: xerces-c

Currently, My code uses Xerces-C 2.7, but due to requirement I was asked to migrate to Xerces-c 3.X. I couldn't find any official detailed document that can help me in achieving the same.I am using wrapper on the top of xerces-C 2.X that makes me more uncomfortable to port my code to use Xerces-C 3.X.With different link I was able to write the standalone code to Read and write XML using latest Xerces.(Took help : [Xerces-C: Migration from v2.x to v3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678396/xerces-c-migration-from-v2-x-to-v3-x)).
Does is it right choice whether to port my code for 2.X to 3.X or write a new library?
I am not aware, if any Xerces 2.X code is compatible with stdC++11 ?If yes, Kindly Let me know the version along with the Link from where I can get the code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

We didn't  migrate the code.As a temporary way,to support C++11 feature, we build the xerces2.X with c++11 flag and was able to successfully link to the library.